# When is the copy of files to iCloud done?

Tags: macos, icloud, finder

I copied files under my filesystem on Mac (saved to hard disk) to iCloud directory (`~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs`). The copy took 3 hours (about 40GB file I think) with the indicator on a separate window on Finder. And I assumed that after that, the copy is done.

Then, after the copy seems to have finished, I found there is another indicator on the bottom of Finder main window, and these seems to be that files are going to be uploaded. There are also icons on each file, some with the cloud icon and some with dotted cloud icon, and some without any.

So I wonder, is the upload still under progress? If that is the case, then how can I know whe the upload will be done? Right now the status bar only shows how many files are going to be uploaded, but I don't know how many in total, so cannot know appoximately when they are done.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go you [www.icloud.com](http://www.icloud.com) to check out if all your files have been uploaded successfully. The uploading or downloading indicator doesn't work so well sometimes on macOS, especially when you're logging with an Apple ID in another country. BTW, not everyone can read Chinese here, please try to upload a picture with English description next time.